# Using SetTimeout to Delay a Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that checks if to see if a game is over that I want to delay to give the user time to see if each answer is correct before seeing the game over screen.

The game ov er check works fine when it's run with no time out, but when I set the timeout I get the error that the function call is not a function.

```
setTimeout(function() {this.CheckGameOver();}, (5 * 1000));
```

Is there something wrong with the way the Timeout is being set? That's the only think could be the problem as the function works perfectly on it's own.

```
CheckGameOver: function() {
        // Check game over clause
        var c = this.View.children;

        if (this.players[0].answered == 13) { // Check if Player 1 won
            // Win the game
            gameStopped = true;
            isFirstQuestionSetup = true;

            if(this.PlayerCount == 1) {
                views.get('singlePlayerGame').transitionOut();
                clearInterval(this.cpu);
            } else {
                views.get('twoPlayerGame').transitionOut();
            }
            views.get('background').switchState(BACKGROUND_STATES.GAME_OVER);
            views.get('genericHud').switchState(HUD_STATES.MAIN_MENU);
            views.get('gameOver').transitionIn(this.players, this.GameType, this.Language);

        } 

        if (this.playerCount == 1) {
            if (this.cpuAnswered == 13) { // Check if CPU won
                // Lose the Game (Doh!)
                gameStopped = true;
                views.get('singlePlayerGame').transitionOut();
                clearInterval(this.cpu);
                views.get('background').switchState(BACKGROUND_STATES.GAME_OVER);
                views.get('genericHud').switchState(HUD_STATES.MAIN_MENU);
                views.get('gameOver').transitionIn(this.players, this.GameType, this.Language);
            }
        } else {
            if (this.players[0].answered == 13) { // Check if Player 2 won
                // Player 2 Wins
                gameStopped = true;
                views.get('twoPlayerGame').transitionOut();
                views.get('background').switchState(BACKGROUND_STATES.GAME_OVER);
                views.get('genericHud').switchState(HUD_STATES.MAIN_MENU);
                views.get('gameOver').transitionIn(this.players, this.GameType, this.Language);
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: setTimeout(function() {this.CheckGameOver();}, 5000);  Are you try with numeric value

Comment: The problem might be with `this`. When the timeout callback gets called, `this` would point to the object that generated the event (probably `window`). Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Is there anyway around using .this at all? - I'll try with a numeric value just in case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside the setTimeout function doesn't refer to what you think it does. You can either use an es6 arrow function

```
setTimeout(() => {this.CheckGameOver();}, (5 * 1000));
```

or bind `this` to `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function() {this.CheckGameOver();}.bind(this), (5 * 1000));
```

Comment: Used `.bind(this)` and that fixed the issue - thanks!

Comment: The arrow function is not yet fully cross-browser as it currently only works on Firefox.

Comment: @emiliopedrollo that's not true, it also works in chrome. But you're right, all of the es6 features are not yet cross browser - that's why I added an es5 compatible version to the answer

Comment: My bad, the compatibility chart that I checked was outdated. Indeed it's largely supported now, with the usual exception of IE.

Comment: @emiliopedrollo IE is always years behind yeah... :-)

Answer (score 0):

It happens that the anonymous function inside `setTimeout` is in a different closure than anything outside it thus `this` is something different and does not have such functions.

You should, outside `setTimeout` set something like

```
var that = this;
```

and inside `setTimeout` call for `that.CheckGameOver()` so it will solve your closure problem.

Alternatively, if all you have to do within a delay is to call CheckGameOver you can write your line like this:

```
setTimeout(this.CheckGameOver, (5 * 1000));
```